# Merge two images in php

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I have two images I would like to merge then save to a new location.
I would like the second image to be place directly below the first image.
I have the following so for but the image doesn't even save.

```
$destimg = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/myimg.jpg');

$src = imagecreatefromgif('images/second.gif');  

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($destimg, $src, 316, 100, 0, 0, 316, 100, 100);
```

Both images have a width or 316px X 100px
From the above code the $destimg should now be 316x200 but that doesn't happen. Also like it to be a new image and save to another folder.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you seen the version of your PHP and the version that's needed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added php 5 in the description but it was removed from mods I think.

Comment: To merge vertically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50045143/9370144

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best approach for this situation may be to create a new image in memory with the combined dimensions you desire, then copy or resample the existing images to the new image, and then save the new image to disk.

For example:

```
function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result) {

 // Get dimensions for specified images

 list($width_x, $height_x) = getimagesize($filename_x);
 list($width_y, $height_y) = getimagesize($filename_y);

 // Create new image with desired dimensions

 $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_x + $width_y, $height_x);

 // Load images and then copy to destination image

 $image_x = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_x);
 $image_y = imagecreatefromgif($filename_y);

 imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
 imagecopy($image, $image_y, $width_x, 0, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);

 // Save the resulting image to disk (as JPEG)

 imagejpeg($image, $filename_result);

 // Clean up

 imagedestroy($image);
 imagedestroy($image_x);
 imagedestroy($image_y);

}
```

Example:

```
merge('images/myimg.jpg', 'images/second.gif', 'images/merged.jpg');
```

Comment: It would be wise to include better error handling by checking the result of imagecreatetruecolor and imagecreatefromjpeg. I neglected this for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to add one more thing here if you are using PHP GD Library,then you should include `imagesavealpha()` and `alphablending()` also.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Image Magick instead (pecl-imagick module or running it as command via shell). I have several reasons:

Imagick is:

- faster
- knows more format
- makes better quality images
- have more ability (for example text rotation)
- and more...

Your method is Imagick::compositeImage if you use the php module. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-compositeimage.php

Answer (score -5):

I found the answer, use GD:

```
 function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result) {

 // Get dimensions for specified images

 list($width_x, $height_x) = getimagesize($filename_x);
 list($width_y, $height_y) = getimagesize($filename_y);

 // Create new image with desired dimensions

 $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_x, $height_x);

 // Load images and then copy to destination image

 $image_x = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_x);
 $image_y = imagecreatefromgif($filename_y);

 imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
                        //  top, left, border,border
 imagecopy($image, $image_y, 100, 3100, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);

 // Save the resulting image to disk (as JPEG)

 imagejpeg($image, $filename_result);

 // Clean up

 imagedestroy($image);
 imagedestroy($image_x);
 imagedestroy($image_y);

}
```

like this:

```
merge('images/myimage.jpg', 'images/second.gif', 'images/merged.jpg');
```

Comment: That answer is above.